# Three JS - sao post processing don't affected by fog

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, post-processing

I have a scene with several objects (cubes), in that scene I'm using fog, I aplied sao post processing, but it won´t be affected by the fog ( sao is aplied over fog).

How do I make the fog affect the sao?

I'm using Three.js r95 in Chrome (Windows).

```
// INIT SCENE
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xffffff, 1, 200 );
```

....

```
var saoPass = new THREE.SAOPass( scene, camera, false, true );
composer.addPass( saoPass );
```

Thanks.